# Cómo gestionar una transacción java spring con llamadas a métodos pl/sql que usan una EntityManager comun a la aplicación

Tags: java, spring, plsql, transacciones

Tengo que hacer una trasacción en java que haga rollback en un método java que llama a métodos pl/sql usando el mecanísmo de persistencia de Spring (se trata de un proyecto heredado desarrollado de una determinada manera).

PROBLEMA:El código no me falla pero el rollback de la transacción no desace las operaciones de base de datos realizadas dentro de los métodos pl/sql invocados. El código usado sería:

Para realizar la transacción:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
public TipoObjeto enviarYRegistrar( Usuario objUsuario, TipoObjeto, boolean  String id) throws Exception   {
  TipoObjeto obj = XXXXX(..........); //metodo java llama metodos pl/sql
   //si va bien
   Strint texto= YYYYY(.....); //llamada método java 

   if (error en XXXXX)
      throws new Exception(....);  //para hacer rollback
   if (error en YYYYY)
       throws new Exception(....);
   return obj;
```

}

Los métodos java que llaman a métodos pl/sql están declarados en clase ZZZZZ con:

```
@Autowired IPersistenciaXXX persistenciaXXX;
```

Método java que invoca método pl/sql:

```
private TipoObjeto enviar(TipoObjeto objeto1){........
Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>(); //param va está relleno con los parametros necesarios
List<Object> listaResultados = (List<Object>) persistenciaXXX.procedimientoAlmacenado("metodoPSql", param);
.....}
```

Donde procedimientoAlmacenado está en la clase PersistenciaXXX:

```
@Component("persistenciaXXX")
@Repository
@Transactional
public class PersistenciaXXX implements IPersistenciaXXX {
private EntityManager entityManager;

 @PersistenceContext (unitName= "PROYECTOJPA")
 public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
 }
 ........
 public Object procedimientoAlmacenado(String procedimiento,
    Map<String, Object> parametros) throws Exception {

EntityManager entityManager = null;
try {
    entityManager = getEntityManager();
    Query query = entityManager
            .createNamedQuery(procedimiento);
    for (String s : parametros.keySet()){
          query.setParameter(s,parametros.get(s));  
    }
    Object listResults = (Object)query.getResultList();
    return listResults;
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new Exception("Error : " + e.getMessage());
} finally {
    if (entityManager != null)
        entityManager.close();
}
}
```

Donde persistence.xml está definido:

```
<persistence version="2.0" ......>
<persistence-unit name="PROYECTOJPA" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">    
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<non-jta-data-source>jdbc/cxPROYECTOCoreDS</non-jta-data-source>
<mapping-file>META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml</mapping-file>
<class> ....</class>
<class>........</class>
<properties>
  <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="false" />
  <property name="eclipselink.deploy-on-startup" value="true"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.session.customizer" value="aaaa.bbbb.ccccc.control.persistenciaXXX.SessionCustomizer"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.cache.coordination.protocol" value="jms"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.cache.coordination.jms.topic" value=": jms/PROYECTOTopic"/>
   <property name="eclipselink.cache.coordination.jndi.password" value=".........................."/>
  <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="WebLogic_10"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
  </properties>  
  </persistence-unit>
  </persistence>
```

Donde eclipselink-orm.xml contiene el mapeo entre los nombres del método pl/sql y los parámetros invocados por java y el paquete.metodo de pl/sql y parametros en pl/sql. 
Ejemplo de mapeo:

```
<named-stored-procedure-query name="enviar" procedure-name="PAQUETEX.enviar" returns-result-set="false">
<parameter direction="IN" name="p_in" query-parameter="p_in" type="String"/>      
<parameter direction="OUT" name="p_out" query-parameter="p_out" type="java.sql.Clob"/>
</named-stored-procedure-query>
```

En el spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml está incluida el soporte de JPA, la definición de la unidad de persistencia y la gestión de transacciones mediante anotaciones:

Cómo puedo conseguir que la transacción realice un commit y un rollback que deshaga las operaciones de los métodos pl/sql sin reescribir los métodos en pl/sql?
Todo el negocio del proyecto esta realizado en pl/sql, las clases java hacen la entrada/salida de la aplicación web.

Gracias

Comment: Según entiendo, deberías usar `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED` en lugar de `PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW` y tu código funcionaría, asumiendo que ambos componentes de Spring están usando el mismo `transactionManager`

Answer (score 1):

Antes de romperte la cabeza intentando averiguar cómo hacer eso, ¿has comprobado que el código que se ejecuta en los `PL/SQL` no haga un `START TRANSACTION/COMMIT`?

Por la descripción que das, podría ser ese el caso (no es nada fuera de lo común), lo que te impediría hacer `rollback` desde arriba porque, cuando recuperas el control, la transacción que crea el PL/SQL ya ha sido confirmada.

Si ese fuese el escenario, deberías ver si es factible quitar los START `TRANSACTION/COMMIT` de los `PL/SQL` y entonces sí podrías gestionar la transacción desde tu código, pero como digo, has de estar segura que no se hace uso de esos `PL/SQL` desde otros puntos de la aplicación y ese cambio no provoca resultados imprevistos.

Comment: Aunque esto fuese cierto, si la conexión abierta desde Java manda iniciar una transacción, entonces esa es la que dirige la transaccionabilidad. Aunque ejecutes 2 o más sentencias PL/SQL, cada una dentro de un bloque transaccional, si la transacción a nivel de aplicación indica que debe haber un rollback, lo habrá.

Comment: Correcto, pero en cierta ocasión me encontré con problemas por PL/SQLs invocados desde Spring, donde se montaba la transacción, cuando intentaban crear su propia transacción por cómo estaba configurado el servidor de BD

Comment: También es importante ver el tipo de transacción que se define en Spring. Por eso en mi comentario a la pregunta indico que cambiando la estrategia puede resolverse el problema,